# Can I use SIMD (C++) when I am accessing the same memory location with different indexes?

Tags: c++, vectorization, openmp, simd

I am currently trying to parallelize with OMP SIMD a for loop which has multiple indirections, i.e., gather and scatter operations.

I initialize parallelized with

```
#pragma omp for
```

and i verified the correctness of the output. Nevertheless, when including SIMD into it, i have a problem with the memory locations i am writing to.

I describe the details next:

1. I am solving a linear system of equations Ax=b
2. The matrix A is assembled in a unordered way. This is a restriction because of previous steps in the algorithm, so the matrix is updated like this:

```
#pragma omp for schedule(static) // or pragma omp for simd schedule(static)
for (int idx = 0; d <= num_elements; idx++) {

  int loc = location(idx);

  double factor1 = value(loc + 3);
  double factor2 = value(loc + 4);

  double val = factor1 * factor2;

  int N12 = location[loc + 4];
  matrixPointer[N12] -= val

}
```

The problem here is that N12 can be the same value for several idx.
Because of this, when I check the output, the debugging output looks like this for one specific index:

```
with omp for
idx = 1, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = 0.000000000E+00 - 1.000000000E-10 = -1.000000000E-10 
idx = 2, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = -1.000000000E-10 - 1.000000000E-10 = -2.000000000E-10 
idx = 3, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = -2.000000000E-10 - 1.000000000E-10 = -3.000000000E-10 
idx = 4, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = -3.000000000E-10 - 1.000000000E-10 = -4.000000000E-10

with omp for simd
idx = 1, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = 0.000000000E+00 - 1.000000000E-10 = -1.000000000E-10 
idx = 2, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = 0.000000000E+00 - 1.000000000E-10 = -1.000000000E-10 
idx = 3, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = -1.000000000E-10 - 1.000000000E-10 = -2.000000000E-10 
idx = 4, val: 1.000000000E-10, mat[153568] = -1.000000000E-10 - 1.000000000E-10 = -2.000000000E-10
```

I tried using fences or atomic operations but this was not possible (did not compile), i guess because SIMD is not designed to have fences inside of it.

I am not sure if i can call this a race condition or an issue with cache coherence, but in any case, **does anyone know if this issue can be avoided AND still use SIMD?**

Thanks :)

Comment: Hi Daniel, I think this is a race condition as multiple simd operations are trying to write to the same location in memory and so one of the operations may have read the original value of N12 but write after another operation. I would guess there could be a way to restructure this using a reduction operation but this may not help you as it could introduce a possible slowdown as the reduction may not be over consecutive elements of an array.

Comment: Even without SIMD your algorithm does not look save, since (on most architectures) there is no atomic `memory -= value` operation. It is hard to tell what actually happens or how to rewrite this in a SIMD-suitable way, without a proper [mre].

Comment: "i verified the correctness of the output": how? Did you compare the **whole** matrix to the one of the serial  version, or just a few elements? Even without simd this code is wrong if `N12` can have the same value in different iterations.

Comment: Does it have to be with OpenMP? AVX512CD for example offers a workaround, although the conflict detection is only efficient on *some* implementations. IDK how to use that with OpenMP, but it can be used through manual vectorization. That doesn't fix the race condition across multiple threads though.

Comment: @JoelKandiah, in the multi-threaded fashion (without SIMD), i actually do not write to the same memory location since every thread has kind of an block of the matrix. After the for loop, there is indeed a reduction step, or an assembly step. And the algorithm actually has quite some gather/scatter operations, which definitely makes the reading/writing slow.

Comment: @chtz Thanks for the link. I will work on the minimal reproducible example to share it here. Also, is it even possible to do an atomic operation using SIMD? I'm honestly confused about that as I did not find information about it, and my knowledge so far tells me it is not possible.

Comment: @PierU yes, i verified the whole matrix to the one of the serial version.

Comment: @harold thanks for the heads up, maybe it can work out. I will read more about it.

Comment: I think you're just lucky if the result is correct, maybe for instance because the likelyhood of 2 threads having simultaneously the same N12 value is quite low. But this doesn't make the code correct.

Comment: @DanielCalle You could gather/scatter from/to 8 independent arrays -- or if conflicts are rare, check for duplicates in the indexes (again hard to tell what is the best solution without more information -- I don't even know if `location` is a function or an array in your case ...).

Comment: @DanielCalle if this is true there may be a way for you to rearrange the original matrix such that at each step the call to location are nonequal at each step but the inputs for each simd step are in contiguous memory (because you can likely know the max size of the simd array by the data type - this may be bad practice if you aren't targetting a single machine however). It would require significantly more information however for me to know whether this is possible.